# What is price of time-slicing?

Tags: multithreading, context-switch

Let's use simple example. I have **1 core** and **1 thread** in pool that has two CPU-bound tasks that last a very long time. Since one thread is run on 1 core, it would be uninterrupted from beginning to an end. And then it runs the second task.

But let's make this funny. I add another thread in pool (size=2) and I still work on that 1 core. Now I make thread 1 work with task 1 and thread 2 work with task 2. This is bad because i would get famous *time-slicing*.

What is the price I am paying for introducing it? What does time-slicing need to do to switch from thread 1 to thread 2 and opposite?
Any helpful resource would be good. I need to know what needs to be load again when OS changes threads it executes.

Comment: The term for that is [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

Comment: Oh thanks finally got it. I was searching by different term all this time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I make thread 1 work with task 1 and thread 2 work with task 2. This is bad because i would get famous time-slicing.

There's not necessarily anything bad about it; it allows the computer to make progress on both tasks at once, which is often what you want.

> What is the price I am paying for introducing it?

The price is that your OS's scheduler will have to do a context-switch every so-many milliseconds -- which isn't usually a big deal since the scheduler's quantum (i.e. the amount of time it lets pass before switching from executing one thread to the other) is tuned to be long enough that the overhead of doing a context-switch is negligible.

The other price is that with two tasks in progress at the same time, the computer must keep both tasks' data in RAM at the same time, meaning a higher maximum RAM usage than in the one-task-at-a-time case.  Whether that is significant or not depends on how much RAM your two tasks use.  Switching back and forth between two data sets might also reduce the effectiveness of the CPU's caches somewhat, if one task's working-set would largely fit into the cache space available but both tasks' working-sets would not.

> What does time-slicing need to do to switch from thread 1 to thread 2
> and opposite?

To do a context switch, the OS's scheduler has to react to a timer-interrupt (that causes the scheduler-routine to run), save the current values of all of the CPU-core's registers into a RAM buffer, then load the other thread's register-values from (the RAM buffer where they were previously saved) back into the CPU-core's registers, and then set an interrupt-timer for the next time the scheduler will need to run.